# Android-Move view from column 1 to column 2 if column 1 overflows

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, multiple-columns, android-tablelayout, android-compound-view

I have a number of custom views that can expand on a click event and they push down views below them.

This may result in some views completely or partially out of screen. I want to detect these occurrences and move them to column two of the screen.

Both columns take half of the screen size.

I do not want to use Listview or anything scroll-able, just move views from column 1 to column 2 and back if space is free.

EDIT: I am trying to override each views onDraw, so it can check if bottom coordinates is below screen y coordinates and then reparent them to a pre-defined Layout. But so far no success.

EDIT2: I managed to detect if a view is out of screen space.
For future reference: i have overriden the dispatchDraw of my custom view class, where i calculated its bottom position and the screen height with: context.getresources().getdisplaymetrics().heightpixels;

Comment: can you give screenshot for reference?

Comment: I cannot as it is work related and i am not allowed to share anything.
Imagine it as an expanding recyclerview: https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Except it is not a listview but separate compound views. But the push-down mechanics are quite the same.

Comment: you dont use list  but if u want i suggest one recyclerview library for all your functionality covered
https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview